# Отправка пуш уведомления через тг бота на html

Tags: html

Всем привет.
Мне нужно написать телеграмм бота, который при нажатии на кнопку отправляет пуш уведомление на html форме.
Элементарный пример
У меня есть такой параметр в css
.Popup{
display:none;}
При нажатии на кнопку в тг боте ‘отправить пуш уведомление’ параметр должен меняться на
.Popup{
display: block; }
Обычно я использую openserver.
А код тг бота запускаю на рабочей машине.
Каким образом я могу реазиловать данный метод?
Нужна работа по сессиям к каждому пользователю отдельно.Отправка пуш уведомления без обновления страницы.
У меня есть пару связок что и как учить
aiogram + django + flask
aiogram + flask + jswebhook in html
Посоветуйте видеоуроки, гайды , документалки, статьи. Я не нашел ничего связанного с моим запросом.

Comment: добро пожаловать на сайт !!! Yahocuparudomov, полезная ссылка, как задать качественный  вопрос на данном ресурсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask